# Windows OpenSSH server on two ports/two shells

Tags: windows-10, openssh

I have OpenSSH server running on Windows 10 Creators build 21354; can I run OpenSSH server on two ports, and land in separate shells depending on the port I connect to? I'd like to be able to bash and cmd depending on the port.

edit: I've found c:\programdata\ssg\sshd_config and added a 2nd `Port` (`Port 122`) line and adjusted windows firewall, but I still don't know how to set up a different shell for each login.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed the creators build two weeks ago, and it claims to be up to date when I check for updates. I know I don't have to run multiple daemons to get multiple ports, I just don't know how to set up openssh server on windows to listen to multiple ports. On linux I know how to do this.

Comment: @retorquere You're running an updated build [Insider's from ~2021.04.07] and Win32-OpenSSH supports most OpenSSH parameter options _(there are ~20 something parameters that are not/will not be ported over, but the config is located at `%ProgramData%\ssh\sshd_config`)_, with [`ListenAddress`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ListenAddress) being the parameter to use

Comment: @retorquere - Are you indicating your running an **Insider Preview** build? Creators Update refers to a build released in 2017; There is nothing formally referred to as a “Creators” build. You still won’t be able to run multiple instances of the deamon

Comment: Oh apologies -- the "about this PC" says Win10 Edu, version dev, OS Build 21387.1, Experience Windows 10 Feature Experience Pack 321.13101.0.3